# python: create a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a number of files that I am reading in. I would like to have a list that contains the file contents. I read the whole content into a string.

I need a list that looks like this:

```
["Content of the first file", "content of the second file",...]
```

I have tried various ways like `append`, `extend` or `insert`, but they all expect a `list` as parameter and not a `str` so I end up getting this:

```
[["Content of the first file"], ["content of the second file"],...]
```

How can I get a list that contains strings and then add strings without turning it into a list of lists?

**EDIT**
 Some more code

```
for file in os.listdir("neg"):
    with open("neg\\"+file,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        linesNeg.append(f.read().splitlines())

for file in os.listdir("pos"):
    with open("pos\\"+file,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        linesPos.append(f.read().splitlines())

listTotal = linesNeg + linesPos
```

Comment: `append` should work.  It takes anything, not just a list

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Based on the second output (which you are getting), the place where you are doing `.append()`, use `.extend()`

Comment: Make sure that linesNeg and linesPos exist before you try to append to them

Comment: @anonymous extend did the trick

Answer (score 2):

```
contents_list = []
for filename in filename_list:
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents_list.append(f.read())
```

Comment: `.append()` instead of `.append[]` i.e `[]` -> `()`

Comment: Thats what I am doing but then I get a list of lists and not a list of strings. When I print listNeg or listTotal, they are lists of lists of strings.

Comment: @user3813234 that's because you're doing `splitlines`  Do you want `["contents file1", "contents file2"]` or `["file1 line1", "file1 line2", "file2 line 1"]`

Comment: @Patrick Haugh The former: ["entire content file one", "entire content file two",...]

Comment: @user3813234 then don't use `splitline`.  it takes a string and makes it a list of strings, exactly what you don't want

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely more than one way to do it. Assuming you have the opened files as file objects `f1` and `f2`:

```
alist = []
alist.extend([f1.read(), f2.read()])
```

or

```
alist = [f.read() for f in (f1, f2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd do something like this, but there's more than one way to skin this cat.

```
file_names = ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt']

def get_string(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fh:
        contents = fh.read()
    return contents

strings = [get_string(f) for f in file_names]
```